# STM32 CubeIDE Place a static library in specified memory region and mapped to the absolute memory address

Tags: stm32, gnu, linker-scripts, stm32cubeide

I have an STM32 CubeIDE project.
I want to place a static library in an absolute memory address in the upper part of the internal flash while the application code will be placed at the beginning of the flash.
But the content of the library is allocated under the text region with the application code

I did this in the linker script:

```
MEMORY
{
  ROM    (rx)               : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 244K
  LIB_region (rx)           : ORIGIN = 0x0803D000, LENGTH = 4K 
  RAM1   (xrw)              : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 32K
  RAM2   (xrw)              : ORIGIN = 0x20009000, LENGTH = 28K
}
...
my_lib_section : 
{
    *(libTestLib.a)
} > LIB_region
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to include all the sections of a file using the following syntax:

```c
my_lib_section : 
{
    libTestLib.a
} > LIB_region
```

See the [section placement](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_chapter/ld_3.html#SEC19) section of the GNU linker command language manual:

> filename
>
> You may simply name a particular input file to be placed in the current output section; all sections from that file are placed in the current section definition.

If you just wanted the .text section from the library, this should work:

```c
my_lib_section : 
{
    libTestLib.a (*.text)
} > LIB_region
```